# udp data not recieved in windows socket program

Tags: c, udp, winsock, windows-socket-api

I am new to windows socket programming. I have a device which gives udp data through a port, ipv6 protocol based. I am trying to capture this in a console application written in visual studio in Windows 7. Socket creation and bind are successful but nothing is recieved from the port specified.

I have done this in Linux since i am basically a linux system software developer and it is working perfect. Is there anything else i need to do to get UDP packets in windows. I have checked with wireshark in windows and found that the UDP packets are coming from the device to the PC.

Working Code Done in Linux:

```
int main()
{
        struct sockaddr_in6 ipv6_addr;
        int addrlen, ipv6_sockfd, cnt, err;
        char response[200], cmd[500];
        cJSON *param, *root;

        memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
        ipv6_sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
        if (ipv6_sockfd < 0) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        bzero((char *)&ipv6_addr, sizeof(ipv6_addr));
        ipv6_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        ipv6_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        ipv6_addr.sin6_port = htons(DISCOVERY_PORT);
        addrlen = sizeof(ipv6_addr);

        if (bind(ipv6_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&ipv6_addr, sizeof(ipv6_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("bind");
            exit(1);
        }

        cnt = recvfrom(ipv6_sockfd, response, sizeof(response), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&ipv6_addr, &addrlen);
        if (cnt < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }

        DBG("Response = \"%s\"\n", response);
        close(ipv6_sockfd);
}
```

Code in Windows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DISCOVERY_PORT 13006
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //UDP Data
    int addrlen, msglen;
    char message[300];
    int err, opt = 1;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in6 hum, addr;

    //Initializing winsock
    WSADATA wsa;
    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed Initializing Winsock EROR CODE : %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    //UDP Socket creation
    s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("\nUDP socket creation failed ERROR CODE : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //UDP socket definition
    memset(&hum, 0, sizeof(addr));
    hum.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    hum.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    hum.sin6_port = htons(DISCOVERY_PORT);

    //UDP SOCKET Binding 
    if (bind(s, (sockaddr *)&hum, sizeof(hum)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nUDP socket binding failed ERROR CODE : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //UDP Receiving data
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    msglen = recvfrom(s, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
    if (msglen == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nUDP Broadcast not received ERROR CODE : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nMessage: %s\n", message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ho about your firewall settings? Have you checked those?

Comment: I have tested by disabling windows firewall but still helpless..

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a client-server connection over the udp protocol (for handling mouse and keyboard input from smartphone), the only difference is that I used ipv4 instead. Same thing - it perfectly worked on linux, but on windows I didn't see any incoming packet.

The thing that worked to me was to run the program as Administrator and also manually add it to firewall's permissions. In general this wasn't stable on some windows PC's, but after installing my server part program to C:\Program Files it has started to work more or less ok.